# Google maps - Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a button which if clicked displays the users location on a map. Currently tough I get this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'position' of undefined`

This is my code:

```
            <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-4">
             <input type="button" value="Show my location on Map" id="mapButton">
                <article></article>
            </div>

$('#mapButton').click(function() {
$( "#mapcontainer" ).remove();
function success(position){
  var mapcanvas = document.createElement('div');
  mapcanvas.id = 'mapcontainer';
  mapcanvas.style.height = '300px';
  mapcanvas.style.width = '300px';

  document.querySelector('article').appendChild(mapcanvas);

  var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
  alert(coords);
  var options = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: coords,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    navigationControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
    },
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map =  new google.maps.Map("mapcontainer",options)[0];

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: coords,
      map: map,
      title:"You are here!"
  });
}

if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);
} else {
  error('Geo Location is not supported');
}
```

});

Why does it throw this error?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kpb9cdhh/1/)

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First parameter to map, is a div element. instead of passing 'mapcontainer', pass

> document.getElementById("mapcontainer")

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/kpb9cdhh/8/)

```
 var map =  new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcontainer"),options)[0];
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          'position': coords,
          map: map,
          title:"You are here!"
      });
```